# Should I declare WaitHandle(s) volatile?

Tags: c#, volatile, event-handling

Should `WaitHandle`s and other synchronization objects which are used by multiple threads be declared as `volatile` ?

Comment: @Xaqron
: don't take this the wrong way, BUT, the fact you are asking that question means you are likely doing something wrong...

Comment: In fact I've got a race condition that suspects me of this. What if when a thread is going to `WaitOne()` another thread `Set()` the object ?

Comment: @Xaqron: have you ever seen an example of a volatile event handler?

Comment: I don't see how eventhandlers qualify as synchronization objects. Are you thinking of WaitHandles?

Comment: @Xaqron: If you're setting that variable, _you're doing it wrong_.  If you're not, `volatile` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Simon: Yes I meant `WatHandles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`volatile` is only relevant if you are re-assigning a field.
For EventHandlers, the [compiler will handle thread-safety](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx); you shouldn't worry about it.

For other synchronization objects, you (probably) shouldn't be reassigning variables in the first place.  (that's not the same as mutation)
Use `readonly`, not `volatile`.

Comment: from a previous recent question posted by @Xaqron, they are having threading issues and trying to solve via the "suck it and see" method.

Comment: @Mitch: This is not about that question (logger)

Comment: @Xaqron: NO. but both questions are essentially about threading and the unfamiliarity thereof.